# JS Regex lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I want to be able to match these types of strings (comma separated, and no beginning or trailing spaces):

> LaunchTool[0].Label,LaunchTool[0].URI,LaunchTool[1].Label,LaunchTool[1].URI,LaunchItg[0].Label,LaunchItg[0].URI,csr_description

The rules, in English, are:

```
1) Zero or more instances of [] where the brackets must contain only one number 0-9
2) Zero or more instances of ., where . must be followed by a letter
3) Zero or more instances of _, where _ must be followed by a letter
```

I currently have this regex:

```
/^([a-z]){1,}(\[[0-9]\]){0,}(\.){0,}[a-z]{1,}$/i
```

I cannot figure out why

`"aaaa"` doesn't match

furthemore,

`"aaaa[0].a"` matches, but `"aaaa[0]"` does not...

anyone know what's wrong? I believe I might need a lookahead to make sure . and _ characters are followed by a letter? Perhaps I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

1. this regex can match "aaaa", try getting value of

`(/^([a-z]){1,}(\[[0-9]\]){0,}(\.){0,}[a-z]{1,}$/i).test("aaaa")`

2. "aaaa[0]" does not match, because there is `[a-z]{1,}` in the end of expression. once "[0]" is matched by `(\[[0-9]\]){0,}`, trailing `[a-z]{1,}` must be shown at the end of string

Comment: and try using `*` / `+`. it is much convenient way to express `{0,}` / `{1,}`

Comment: thanks, I am just learning JS regex, and I find the {} notation easier at first, because I cannot remember the shortcuts

Comment: none of the online tests say that "aaa" or any simple string matches this regex

Answer (score 0):

Use optional capture groups. Example: `([a-z])?`.

Here is what i ended up with:
`/^((\w+)(\[\d+\])?\.?(\w+)?,?)+$/`

Shorthands explanation:

```
 * = {0,}
 + = {1,}
\w = [A-Za-z0-9_]
\d = [0-9]
```